# unable to invoke docker container

Tags: python, docker

Using docker i am unable to invoke the web application from the browser.

The following is the dockerfile used:

```
FROM continuumio/anaconda:latest

Expose 5000

ADD . /code-directory

WORKDIR code-directory

RUN conda install opencv

RUN pip install boto3

RUN pip install boto

RUN pip install flask
RUN pip install pathlib

ADD facedetection_video.py facedetection_video.py

ADD UI_Interface UI_Interface

WORKDIR /UI_Interface

COPY . app.py

RUN python app.py &
```

The following is the contents of app.py

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')

def hello_world():

    return 'Flask Dockerized'

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app.run(debug=True,host='0.0.0.0')
```

The commands used to generate docker image

```
docker build -t test1 .
```

The command used to run the container

```
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 test1
```

The output status message of the container is:

```
Exited (0) 3 minutes ago
```

In the logs I could not find any error message. Pls suggest

Comment: You can `docker run -it test1 /bin/bash` to get a shell prompt to try running commands manually or looking around with `ls` or other commands.

Answer (score 0):

`RUN` is a Dockerfile directive to run a command at build-time to generate an image.

What you need for running the container is to define the `CMD`, which represents the program that **will** run as a container when you execute `docker run ...`

Change:

```
RUN python app.py &
```

To:

```
CMD python app.py
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved.

In the dockerfile there was  error changed the dockerfile as shown below:

FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app 
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN apt-get install -y libavresample-dev

## Various Python and C/build deps

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \

```
wget \
build-essential \ 
cmake \ 
git \
unzip \ 
pkg-config \
python-dev \ 
python-opencv \ 
libopencv-dev \ 
libav-tools  \ 
libjpeg-dev \ 
libpng-dev \ 
libtiff-dev \ 
libjasper-dev \ 
libgtk2.0-dev \ 
python-numpy \ 
python-pycurl \ 
libatlas-base-dev \
gfortran \
webp \ 
python-opencv \ 
qt5-default \
libvtk6-dev \ 
zlib1g-dev
```

RUN apt-get install -y python-pip

RUN mkdir -p ~/opencv

RUN cd ~/opencv

RUN apt-get install -y vim

RUN pip install boto3

RUN pip install boto

RUN pip install flask

RUN pip install pathlib

RUN pip install scikit-video

EXPOSE 5000

COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app

ENTRYPOINT ["python"]

CMD ["app.py"]